# AJAX code fails on Firefox and IE11 but ok on Chrome and Opera

Tags: ajax, firefox

I am learning AJAX and I have a problem with the following code.
This is a HTML page that, when downloaded to a browser, will allow the user to press a button to retrieve a 'clientes.xml' file from the server.
The code looks simple and seems to be in accordance with AJAX theory.

It actually works ok if I use a Chrome or an Opera browser.

The problem is that it always fails on Firefox (v45) and IE11.

By using the browser consoles, the following errors are reported: 
Firefox:   NS_ERROR_FAILURE error in the last line of the script: xhttp.send();
IE11:    'Permission denied' error on the same script line: xhttp.send();

By using Wireshark on the network, I can see that a HTTP GET message is always sent for the 'clientes.xml' file with Chrome and Opera but this never happens with Firefox or IE11.

I have already searched for a possible explanation for this but found none.

Does anyone know what might be the problem with Firefox and IE?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
 var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

 function doStuff(response) {
    // var papeis=response;
    var clientes=response.getElementsByTagName("nome");
    for (i = 0; i < clientes.length; i++) {
        document.write("<p>"); 
        document.write(clientes[i].childNodes[0].textContent);
    }
}

 function sendRequest() {
 var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   if (!xhttp) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log (xhttp.readyState);
        if (xhttp.readyState!=4) {document.write("Not Yet Done: " + xhttp.readyState + "<br>" );}
        else if(xhttp.readyState===4 && xhttp.status===200) {
            doStuff(xhttp.responseXML);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open('GET','clientes.xml', true);
    xhttp.send();
 } 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h3> AJAX </h3> <br>

<button onclick="sendRequest()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where is the problem. The problem is in the javascript document.write() function which I used for testing purposes.
If I replace this function by console.log()  in my sendRequest() function, Firefox will behave the same way as Chrome and Opera.